# How to get mp3 metadata from radio stream (no icecast, no shoutcast)

Tags: php, javascript, mp3, metadata

As the topic says, I need to obtain the metadata from a web radio live stream, the site url is like: http://vps.radioduepuntozero.net:8000/Radio2.0.mp3

is there any way to do it maybe with JavaScript or PHP? 
As you know, the main problem is the remote path of the mp3.

Answer (score 1):

It is a icecast station, you can use file_get_contents here to get all the information you need: `http://vps.radioduepuntozero.net:8000/`

But for a more in-depth answer: The way it works, every mp3 file streamed begins with a section called the ID3 tag. It has information on the author, the album, track name, etc. Because it is streamed live you cannot just pick any frame and read that section. You must wait for the next song to begin to read its ID3 tag.

Also, knowing when a track begins and end is tricky. Icecast will insert frames every X bytes to say how many remaining bytes is left to the song, and what size will be the next packet, etc.

There is a protocol behind it, it's doable, I did it before, but it requires knowledge of PHP sockets and the said protocol. You'd be better with C++ or, like I said,

fetching the icecast station page.

Comment: And if the radio is not broadcasted by icecast?

Comment: I explained everything just above.

Comment: ok thank you, so I've to download a piece of mp3 and to process it.

Comment: Is there any way to obtain all the urls of the radios from xiph.org?

Comment: It's a bit old, I know, but mind to share which protocol is behind it?